# Changing numeric variable to categorical variable?

Tags: r, variables, binary, numeric, logistic-regression

I am a finance student and have been playing around in R the past couple of weeks (Rookie here..).
**QUESTION:** I have two numeric variables: A and B. And I want turn these in one cathegorical variable C. C takes the following values:
*1 if A and B both score top decile – or quintile of the distribution.

0 otherwise*
Does anyone have any idea how to effectuate this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43364844/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your meaning right, You can Use this function:

```
    get_categorical = function(A,B,decile=9){
      da = as.numeric(quantile(A,probs=seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)))[decile];
      db = as.numeric(quantile(B,probs=seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)))[decile];
      categ = ifelse(A>=da & B>db,1,0);
      return (categ);
    }
```

Now you can set A and B as arguments:

```
get_categorical(A,B)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Was able to create the variable as follows: dummyVariabele <- ifelse((Mergeddata$ABS_DA  >= quantile(Mergeddata$ABS_DA,c(0.9),na.rm=TRUE)) & (Mergeddata$RM_Proxy >= quantile(Mergeddata$RM_Proxy,c(0.9),na.rm=TRUE)), 1, 0).